# Doomsday Vs. Extinction - Population Growth Model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the question goes something like this.

Let $P(t)$ be the bunny population in a certain area after $t$ months.

If $P(0)=200$, solve this IVP and show all the steps. Find $P(t)$ explicitly and draw its graph. There is a value of $t=t_{doomsday}$ where, as $t\rightarrow t^-_{doomsday}$, there is a population explosion - a real doomsday situation. Find this value of $t$.

So here I solve the given DE $\frac{dP}{dt}=0.0004P(P-150)$ and through PFD arrive at $\frac{P-150}{P}=Ae^{0.06t}\\$ Is this correct?

From here I am stuck, I know that it is a very simple algebraic move to get the expression in explicit form but I am unable to. I reached out to a few people on various websites and they said it should be this $P(t)=\frac{150}{1-Ae^{0.06t}}$, but to me I am not sure if this correct,and after repeated algebraic moves I am unable to replicate this form. 
Is there anyone who can confirm this?

From here I know to set $P(0)=200$ and solve the IVP. I just need that little clue or hint. I don't want the answer, just to nudge me in the right direction. Please help!!!

Comment: @Amzoti yes clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Amzoti yes indeed I did. For $P(0)=\frac{150}{1−Ae^{0.06(0)}}=200$ and solving for $A\\$ I receive $P(t)=\frac{150}{1−0.25e^{0.06t}}\\$. Now, I think I am stuck because the problem asks to find′There is a value of $t=t_{doomsday}$ where, as $t^−_{doomsday}$, there is a population explosion−a real doomsday situation. Find this value of $t$. I am unsure how to proceed on this. I have scoured my notes, and can only find some general formula where 'In the long run' $P(t)=\frac{aP_0}{bP_0}=\frac{a}{b}\\$
Not sure what the values of $a$ and $b$ would be. Maybe $a=150$ and $b=1$?

Comment: @Amzoti No, I think because this is a Logistic Equation I need to put it in the form $P(t)=\frac{aP_0}{bP_0+(a-bP_0)e^{-at}}$ for $t\geq 0$ Where $a$ for me is $0.06$ and $b$ is $0.04$? I am not sure about this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:  Your equation is correct.  So is the solution you found on the web:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{P-150}{P} = A e^{0.06t} \\
P-150 = A e^{0.06t} P \\
P -  A e^{0.06t} P = 150 \\
P(1- A e^{0.06t}) = 150 \\
P(t) = \frac{150}{1- A e^{0.06t} }
\end{array}
$$
That solution is in fact correct: 
You can easily find the derivative of $P(t)$ and notice that it has a factor of $P$ in it, and that the rest is $0.0004 (P-150)$.

Solving for $A$ is easy because $e^0 = 1$.  Thus $200 = \frac{150}{1-A}$ and the same trick of multiplying by $(1-A$ and then grouping terms (this time with $A$ rather than $P$) works to give $A=\frac{1}{4}$.

Finally, you could find the  doomsday $t$ by seeing when $(1-\frac{1}{4}e^0.06t)$ becomes zero.  This is at Z$t = \frac{\ln 4}{0.06}$ which you probably should simplify to something like 
$$
t = \frac{100\ln 2}{3}
$$

Comment: Which is 23.1 months and yes that is the answer. Thanks Mark. I though I had to find it a different way for some reason.